# Data manipulation based on trends value

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining, data-science, data-manipulation

Given a dataset with Date column and Value column, I need to come up with the best solution of segmenting the data by date based on trends in the Value column. My output should be a CSV filewith the columns: StartDate, EndDate,StartValue,EndValue. Start and End date define the bounds of the segment. 
A short example is presented: input data:

```
 **Date**        **Value**
  01/01/2014        10
  01/02/2014        5
  01/03/2014        5
  01/04/2014        0
```

output:

```
 **StartDate**   **EndDate**   **StartValue**   **EndValue**
   01/01/2014      01/15/2014        10              5
   01/16/2014      02/03/2014         5              5
   02/04/2014      03/10/2014         5              4
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `pandas.DataFrame.shift` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)).

Firstly I'll create a dataframe with some data:

```
import pandas as pd
datelist = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=100).tolist()
values = np.random.randint(1, 5, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': datelist, 'Value': values})
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.head(10)

Date        Value
2019-01-01  1
2019-01-02  4
2019-01-03  2
2019-01-04  2
2019-01-05  2
2019-01-06  3
2019-01-07  2
2019-01-08  2
2019-01-09  3
2019-01-10  2
```

Drop contiguously duplicate rows:

```
df = df.loc[df.Value.shift() != df.Value]

Date        Value
2019-01-01  2
2019-01-02  1
2019-01-04  2
2019-01-05  3
2019-01-06  1
```

Reset the index (if the `Date` column is the index in the original data):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Rename the existing columns to be the start columns.

```
df.columns = ['Start_Date', 'Start_Value']
```

Create end columns by shifting the start columns back one row.

```
df['End_Date'] = df.Start_Date.shift(-1)
df['End_Value'] = df.Start_Value.shift(-1)
```

Drop NaNs (the final row of the dataframe due to the `shift(-1)`.

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Set the `End_Value` type to `int` (if preferred).

```
df['End_Value'] = df['End_Value'].astype(int)
df.head(10)

    Start_Date  Start_Value End_Date    End_Value
0   2019-01-01  1           2019-01-02  4
1   2019-01-02  4           2019-01-03  2
2   2019-01-03  2           2019-01-06  3
3   2019-01-06  3           2019-01-07  2
4   2019-01-07  2           2019-01-09  3
5   2019-01-09  3           2019-01-10  2
6   2019-01-10  2           2019-01-11  1
7   2019-01-11  1           2019-01-12  2
8   2019-01-12  2           2019-01-15  1
9   2019-01-15  1           2019-01-16  4
```

Create a CSV file from the dataframe:

```
df.to_csv('trends.csv')
```